# On Github release/tag UI, what is the difference between first and second form field?

Tags: github, github-release

Regarding this view on the Github UI

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I thought I named it 'api-release-1579814212' but it got named just 'api-release', anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The first field you see (`api-release`) is a tag name.  That specifies the tag your release is associated with.  This should be a valid tag name in your repository.

The second field is the title of your release.  Often it will be the same as the tag name, but sometimes people name their releases (e.g., “v4.5 (Paco's Unboxing)”).  This is purely for humans, and it will appear as a major heading on the releases page.

And, of course, the final field is the body of the release, where you can describe changes or new features, congratulate contributors, provide examples, and so on.

You may also upload release assets, such as tarballs, binaries, and so on below that.